# What is the wrong with "while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){// }"?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried following code in several ways. but problem is occurred always in `"$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)"` ..... `print_r()` method prints the result as an array, that means there is no error with MYSQL query. it gives correct result. problem is in fetch assoc. instead of `'assoc'` I have used  `'array'` as well.

> error says "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, array given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\offoptimizer2\action\fetch_client.php on line 21"

```
class fetch_client{
        public function fetchdata(){
                $phn_number = $_GET["phn"];

                $db_action = new db_action();
                $result = $db_action->select_all("offopt_client","client_phn_no='".$phn_number."'");
                print_r($result);

                echo '<table border="0">';
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th> client name </th>';
                    echo '<th> client phone number </th>';
                echo '</tr>';
                if($result != null){
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            echo '<tr>';
                                echo "<td> ".$row['client_name']." </td>";
                                echo "<td> ".$row['client_phn_no']." </td>";
                            echo '</tr>';   
                            }
                        echo '</table>';
                    }else{
                            echo 'No result';
                        }


            }
    }
```

// this is my select_all function below

```
public function select_all($table_name, $where){
                $db_connect = new db_connect();
                $con = $db_connect->connect();
                if(!$con){
                        echo "Connection error";
                    }else{
                            $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from ".$table_name." where ".$where." ");
                            if(!$query){
                                    echo "Error in your query".mysqli_error($query);
                                }else{
                                        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                                        return $result;
                                    }
                        }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uptate your 'select_all' function as below.

```
public function select_all($table_name, $where){
                $db_connect = new db_connect();
                $con = $db_connect->connect();
                if(!$con){
                        echo "Connection error";
                    }else{
                            $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from ".$table_name." where ".$where." ");
                            if(!$query){
                                    echo "Error in your query".mysqli_error($query);
                                }else{
                                        $result = array();
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                                        array_push($result, $row);
                                        return $result;
                                    }
                        }
            }
```

And now, you can use the `foreach` loop on the result like below:

```
foreach($result as $row)
   echo '<tr>';
   echo "<td> ".$row['client_name']." </td>";
   echo "<td> ".$row['client_phn_no']." </td>";
   echo '</tr>';   
}
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => 4 [client_id] => 4 [1] => dhanapala [client_name] => dhanapala [2] => kotikawatta [client_address] => kotikawatta [3] => 777566892 [client_phn_no] => 777566892 [4] => 14 [ad_id] => 14 )

Comment: Yes... U R CORRECT BUT mysql table contains several rows regarding to given query later.. so what should i do for that??

Comment: You could use an if condition just like you've used for `null`. If you could show the `print_r($result)` when multiple rows are selected, I can update the code.

Comment: your `select_all` function will always return only one row.

Comment: Okay this is final edit, I promise. Update your select_all function and put a loop and it'll work in all conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` need a `ressource` not an `array`. So this looks like your `$db_action->select_all` method return your database data in an array, so performing additional task with the result on `mysqli` functions won't work.

Edit your class behind `$db_action` if you wish to get assoc return data.

Comment: I think same thing done in the following code ..  extracted from "http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php"  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["id"], $row["name"]);
}

Comment: don't mix ``mysqli`` functions with ``mysql`` functions!! There are totally different! Use only ``mysqli`` functions!

Comment: I have just posted my select_all function with question